# Conditional operator without return value

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this code:

```
bool value = false;
if(value)
{
    Console.Write("true");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("false");
}
```

and I want to shorten it by using the conditional operator but I can't find the correct syntax.

```
bool value = false;
value ? Console.Write("true") : Console.Write("false"); // does not work
```

Comment: Why would you want to? All you gain is a few key strokes, and you do lose some readability. You can put it on a single line if you want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the operator inside `Console.Write`

```
Console.Write(value ? "true" : "false");
```

or if you really want to write the value:

```
Console.Write(value);
```

if you want to call 2 different Methods, you can write your if-statement in one line:

```
if (value) Method1(); else Method2();
```

Comment: What if there are 2 different methods instead of `Console.Write` twice

Answer (score 4):

```
    bool value = false;
    Console.Write(value ? "true" : "false");
```

If method returns a value then

```
bool value = false;
var result = value ? Test1() : Test2();

  private int Test1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private int Test2()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: For this specific example, that's fine. But if op was keeping it simple for the sake of the question and in fact was asking about 2 different operations rather than 2 different string values, this doesn't cover it. I suppose you can only work with whatever requirements you've been given tho. So +1.

Comment: What if there are 2 different methods instead of `Console.Write` twice

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some precisions to the previous answer. The reason why you can't do this:

```
value ? Console.Write("true") : Console.Write("false");
```

Is because:

> The conditional operator (?:) **returns** one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

The keyword here is "return". The ternary operator doesn't exactly replace an if/else statement, it is meant for assignment. You can of course call a method within a ternary operation as long as it returns a boolean value. A ternary operator must return something.